# How does one set up OpenStack Swift (object) storage container-specific API keys with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, storage, openstack

I've got the following OpenStack commands for setting up Swift object storage containers:

```sh
openstack container create $CONTAINER_NAME
openstack container set --property Full-Key=$CONTAINER_API_KEY $CONTAINER_NAME
```

I'd like to convert them to Ansible so they can be run as part of a role.

For the first command, I know I can use the [os_object](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_object_module.html) module for creating the container, but it doesn't appear to provide a parameter for setting a property, which in this case is for setting up key access to the container.  (It's based on the documentation at [Container Specific API Keys](http://docs.clouda.ca/bulk-storage/container-keys).)

So how would I execute the second command within Ansible natively, without resorting to running the shell command directly?

Comment: I created an issue for this at [Allow `os_object` to set container properties](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/62760).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it's evident that it's currently impossible to do this natively.  Therefore, we have to do this in the shell with the `command` module:

```sh
command: openstack container set --property Full-Key={{ KEY }} {{ CONTAINER }}
```